# If $f$ is holomorphic and $\lvert\, f\rvert$ is constant, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analyticity, holomorphic-functions

**Claim.** *Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$ and $\,f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. If $\lvert\, f\rvert$ is a constant function, then $f$ is also a constant function.*

I tried to do this like this: Suppose $f=u+iv$. Then from the fact that $\lvert f\rvert=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ is constant we get 
$$\frac{\partial\lvert f\rvert}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \lvert f\rvert}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial \lvert f\rvert}{\partial y}\right)=0$$
$$or,~~~2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0~~~and~~~2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$$
But how do I proceed from here?

Also I need to know, *What would happen if $\Omega$ were not connected?*

Comment: use polar coordinates instead and if $\Omega$ is not connected then it is constant on each connected component.

Comment: The maxiumum principle is the easiest way to prove this (there is actually nothing to prove as soon as you look at the theorem).
Theorem: (Maximum Principle) let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open and connected and $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a non constant holomorphic function. Then the function $z\mapsto|f(z)|$ has no maximum in $\Omega$.

Comment: @b00nheT  Oh, I have done the proof using my approach only, but you seem to give more elegant methods. Can you elaborate how it can be done using polar coordinates or the maximum principle? Moreover I would like to know what would happen if $\Omega$ were not connected.

Comment: Just look at the theorem I wrote down in my previous answer: since it is given that $|f(x)|$ is constant it follows that it also assumes its maximum in $\Omega$ which is in contradiction to the theorem. Hence the function must be constant in all of $\Omega$. Furthermore If $\Omega$ wouldn't have been connected I agree with @viplov_jain that it would be constant on each connected component.

Comment: @b00nheT  I understand these things. However in my approach, by only using the Cauchy-Riemann equations i have solved the problem. There I haven't used the fact that $\Omega$ is connected. Where I am needing that $\Omega$ has to be connected?

Comment: Using the Cauchy Riemann equations you have proven that $u_x=u_y=0$. Now these tell you that the function $f$ is constant on each connected component. Yet these do not tell you that $f$ must be equal to a single constant on the whole open set. Assume for example that you are given the following function: $f:\Omega:=B_\epsilon(1)\cup B_\epsilon(-1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ , $0<\epsilon<1$ s.t $f(z)=1,\ z\in B_\epsilon(1)$ and $f(z)=-1,\ z\in B_\epsilon(-1)$.
This function is holomorphic in the whole given open set and has constant asolute value yet is not constant.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

If $f=u+iv$ and
$$
u^2+v^2=c,
$$
then differentiating by $x$, and using Cauchy-Riemann equations, we get
$$
0=uu_x+vv_x=uv_y-vu_y=(u_y,v_y)\cdot(-v,u)
$$
and by $y$
$$
0=uu_y+vv_y=(u_y,v_y)\cdot(u,v).
$$
Thus the vector $(u_y,v_y)$ is parallel and perpendicular to $(u,v)\ne 0$, and thus 
$$
(u_y,v_y)=(0,0),
$$
everywhere, and using Cauchy-Riemann again, we get that $(u_x,v_x)=(0,0)$, also everywhere.

Thus $u$, $v$ are constant.

**Note.** If $\Omega$ is not connected, then $f$ is constant in each connected component, but it might have a different value in each component.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your approach, you have $u^2+v^2=r^2=const.>0$ and additionally to your derivatives of that equation you have the Cauchy-Riemann PDE, so that you get a regular homogeneous 4x4 system for the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$, rendering them all zero.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u&v&0&0\\
0&0&u&v\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
∂_xu\\∂_xv\\∂_yu\\∂_yv
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

If Ω is not connected, you cannot use that,
if ux=uy=0 then u is constant .
You can check "Complex Analysis", by J.Bak-D.J.Newman, chapter 1, however if you need more information, let me now.